# Подправить JS код

Tags: javascript, form, input, функции

Есть JS код который обрабатывает результаты теста(найден на просторах интернета), но он работает если в тесте 5 вопросов. Как сделать чтобы можно было делать любое количество вопросов?

```js
function count()
{
var answer = 0;
var ball = 0;
var good = "";
var bad = "";
var solv = 1;
  for (var i=0; i<26; i++) {
  if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].value != 0) {
          if (good != "") {
             good += ", "+solv;
          }
          else {
             good += "№ "+solv;
          }
       }
     else {
         if (bad != "") {
             bad += ", "+solv;
          }
          else {
             bad += "№ "+solv;
          }
     }
     solv++;
  }
}
for (var i=0; i<26; i++) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
      answer +=1;
    }
  }
 if (answer < 5) {
     alert("Вы не ответили на все вопросы теста!");
  }
  else {
     if (good == "") good = " нет :(";
     if (bad == "") bad = " нет =)";

var answer = "<span style=color:green>Решены правильно:</span> "+good+ "<br>";
if (bad == "нет") {  answer += "Неправильно: "+bad+"."; }
else { answer += "<span style=color:red>Неправильно:</span>"+bad+ "";}

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("gecko") > 0) { 
  div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
} 
     div1.innerHTML = answer;
     div1.style.display = 'block';

     var paragraphs = document.all.tags('I');
     for (s=0; s< paragraphs.length; s++) {
             if (document.form1.elements[s].checked) {
                 paragraphs(s).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                 if (document.form1.elements[s].value != 0) {
                     paragraphs(s).style.color = 'green';
                 }
                 else {
                     paragraphs(s).style.color = 'red';
                 }
              }
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" class="test">
<p>1. Вопрос 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="1"><i>Вариант 1</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 4</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>
</p>
<p>2. Вопрос 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

</p>
<p>3. Вопрос 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="c" value="1"><i>Вариант 2</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 4</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

</p>
<p>4. Вопрос 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="d" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

</p>
<p>5. Вопрос 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="f" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i><br>
<input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

</p>
<div border="1" id="div1" style="padding:9px 0 11px 10px;margin:9px 17px;border:1px solid green;display:none;"></div>
<input type="button" value="Узнать результат" onclick="count();">
</form>
```

Comment: он здесь ошибку выдает при выполнении, где он работает, где взяли, есть ссылка?

Comment: @CodeGust, fizportal.ru/schoolboy/7-1-1 Только там балл еще подсчитывает, я убрал этот элемент

Comment: @CodeGust, у меня на пк запускается, не знаю почему встроенный редактор не хочет его запускать

Comment: @ilya1099, в IE проверял? :-)

Comment: Код в ответе обновлен, берите последнюю версию! ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Исправление оригинального кода конкретно под данный html код:

```
function count()
{
var answer = 0;
var ball = 0;
var good = "";
var bad = "";
var solv = 1;
  for (var i=0; i<36; i++) {
  if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].value != 0) {
          if (good != "") {
             good += ", "+solv;
          }
          else {
             good += "№ "+solv;
          }
       }
     else {
         if (bad != "") {
             bad += ", "+solv;
          }
          else {
             bad += "№ "+solv;
          }
     }
     solv++;
  }
}
for (var i=0; i<36; i++) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
      answer +=1;
    }
  }
 if (answer < 7) {
     alert("Вы не ответили на все вопросы теста!");
  }
  else {
     if (good == "") good = " нет :(";
     if (bad == "") bad = " нет =)";

var answer = "<span style=color:green>Решены правильно:</span> "+good+ "<br>";
if (bad == "нет") {  answer += "Неправильно: "+bad+"."; }
else { answer += "<span style=color:red>Неправильно:</span>"+bad+ "";}

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("gecko") > 0) { 
  div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
} 
     div1.innerHTML = answer;
     div1.style.display = 'block';

     var paragraphs = document.all.tags('I');
     for (s=0; s< paragraphs.length; s++) {
             if (document.form1.elements[s].checked) {
                 paragraphs(s).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                 if (document.form1.elements[s].value != 0) {
                     paragraphs(s).style.color = 'green';
                 }
                 else {
                     paragraphs(s).style.color = 'red';
                 }
              }
      }
  }
}
```

В цикле, где 26 - добавляем наши вопросы, я добавил 10 (2 секции по 5 вопросов), т.е. я 36 поставил. Где `answer < 5`  - добавляем 2 наши секции, т.е. 7 стает. В Html у каждой группы вопросов должен быть свой, отдельный `name` - это показывает, что группа радиокнопок выбора есть одним блоком для выбора одного элемента из них.

**А вот улучшенная версия Javascript кода (благодаря подсказке об этом Grundy :) ), здесь не нужно вручную ничего менять при добавлении новых блоков вопросов в Html код**:

```js
function count() {
  answer = 0;
  answerBlocksCount = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
  questionsCount = document.form1.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').length + 1;
  var ball = 0;
  var good = "";
  var bad = "";
  var solv = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
      if (document.form1.elements[i].value != 0) {
        if (good != "") {
          good += ", " + solv;
        } else {
          good += "№ " + solv;
        }
      } else {
        if (bad != "") {
          bad += ", " + solv;
        } else {
          bad += "№ " + solv;
        }
      }
      solv++;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) {
    if (document.form1.elements[i].checked) {
      answer += 1;
    }
  }
  if (answer < answerBlocksCount) {
    alert("Вы не ответили на все вопросы теста!");
  } else {
    if (good == "") good = " нет :(";
    if (bad == "") bad = " нет =)";

    var answer = "<span style=color:green>Решены правильно:</span> " + good + "<br>";
    if (bad == "нет") {
      answer += "Неправильно: " + bad + ".";
    } else {
      answer += "<span style=color:red>Неправильно:</span>" + bad + "";
    }

    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("gecko") > 0) {
      div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    }
    div1.innerHTML = answer;
    div1.style.display = 'block';

    var paragraphs = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("i").length;
    for (s = 0; s < paragraphs.length; s++) {
      if (document.form1.elements[s].checked) {
        paragraphs(s).style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        if (document.form1.elements[s].value != 0) {
          paragraphs(s).style.color = 'green';
        } else {
          paragraphs(s).style.color = 'red';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" class="test">
  <p>1. Вопрос 1
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="1"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>
  </p>
  <p>2. Вопрос 2
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <p>3. Вопрос 3
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="1"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="c" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <p>4. Вопрос 4
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="d" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="d" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <p>5. Вопрос 5
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="f" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <p>6. Вопрос 6
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="h" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="h" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="h" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="h" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="h" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <p>7. Вопрос 7
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="j" value="0"><i>Вариант 1</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="j" value="0"><i>Вариант 2</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="j" value="0"><i>Вариант 3</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="j" value="1"><i>Вариант 4</i>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="j" value="0"><i>Вариант 5</i>

  </p>
  <div border="1" id="div1" style="padding:9px 0 11px 10px;margin:9px 17px;border:1px solid green;display:none;"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Узнать результат" onclick="count();">
</form>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYWrYP здесь пробуем.

Comment: просто ужасно :) мало того, что без объяснений, так еще и изменились только константы :)

Comment: @Grundy
объяснение уже добавлено. Код работает.

Comment: и так каждый раз нужно пересчитывать два числа и искать где их надо поменять в коде? :-)

Comment: _Код работает._ - сомнительно _Uncaught TypeError: document.all.tags is not a function_.

Comment: @Grundy
`Uncaught TypeError: document.all.tags is not a function.` это только в кривом редакторе stackoverflow, я же написал, что на codepen нужно идти за проверкой.
Улучшил код для авто подсчет переменных, теперь не нужно JS код менять вручную.

Comment: И за что минусы, когда ответ мой верный и работающий!?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49029/discussion-between-grundy-and-codegust).